# Trouble reading in characters from a .txt file using fscanf

Tags: string, scanf

I am having a problem reading in a portion of a text file using fscanf. The difficulty is only occurring with the characters right before the end of the line.

The text file I am reading in is of the format:

38 59 26.21 N
76 56 24.20 W
...

What I need the code to do is read in the values, convert them into radians and then determine whether or not the sign needs to be adjusted (if it is "W" it needs to be negative).

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {

    // accepts one line of coordinates at a time from the text file
    fscanf_s(f, "%lf %lf %lf %s\n", &deg, &min, &sec, coordinate);

    printf("%s\n", coordinate);

    // converting into radians
    val = (deg*(pi/180)) + ((min/60) * (pi/180)) + ((sec/3600) * (pi/180));

    // checking coordinate to decide whether or not to change the sign
    if ((strcmp(coordinate, "S") == 0) || (strcmp(coordinate, "W") == 0))
    {
        val = val*-1;
    }

    // are dealing with
    if (EVEN(i)) 
    {
        lat[count1][0] = val;
        count1++;
    }
    else 
    {
        lon[count2][0] = val;
        count2++;
    }
}
```

So far this code works perfectly in reading in the floating point numbers in the text file and converting them to radians, however it is not storing the characters at the end of the line for some reason.

I have looked all over and cannot figure out why this is the case.

Thank you for your help!